# backbone and marionette, ItemView not rendering, how to?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, view, marionette

for some reason the ItemView doesn't render. Here is my setup:

controller

```
test: function () {
            require(['application', 'collections/collection-test', 'views/collection/view-test'], function (App, CollectionTest, ViewTest) {
                var collectionTest = new CollectionTest();

                App.regionTest.show(new ViewTest({
                    collection: collectionTest
                }));
            });
        },
```

collection view

```
define(['backbone','views/item/itemview-test'],
function (Backbone, ItemviewTest) {
    'use strict';
    return Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        initialize: function () {},
        itemView: ItemviewTest,
        ui: {},
        events: {},
        /* on render callback */
        onRender: function () {
            console.log(this.$el);
        }
    });
});
```

item view

```
define(['backbone','hbs!tmpl/item/itemview-test_tmpl'],
function (Backbone, ItemviewTestTmpl) {
    'use strict';
    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        initialize: function (options) {},
        template: ItemviewTestTmpl,
        ui: {},
        events: {},
        onRender: function () {
            console.log(this.$el);
        },
    });
});
```

i can see the `<ul></ul>` being added to the region, but not the `li`

i can render the `li` if i replace `'views/collection/view-test'` with `'views/item/itemview-test'` int eh controller, but now i won't get the `ul`

also, if i `console.log(new ItemviewTest())` in the collection, i can see the `ItemView` object with the `$el:'li'` tag, but for some reason it doesn't get added to the html

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ItemView` is rendered for each model in the parent `CollectionView`'s collection. Since the collection is empty, there are no models to render.

Try adding a model:

```
var collectionTest = new CollectionTest([{ name: 'Patrioticcow' }]);

App.regionTest.show(new ViewTest({
  collection: collectionTest
}));
```